# Manually importing gtk fails: module not found

Tags: python, import, gtk

So I would like to execute a python script from command line then and again, and it has to be very quick. Imports in python are [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010255/speeding-up-the-python-import-loader) because *the entire `sys.path` is searched for the respective modules*.

Thus, my idea was to replace

```
import sys
import gdk.gtk
```

with

```
import sys
import imp
imp.load_source("gtk.gdk", "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py")
```

(I got that path from [`os.path.abspath(gtk.__file__)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729605/3779853)

However, python tells me this is invalid: `module 'gtk' not found`. But isn't this exactly what I am trying to import here?

1. what am I doing wrong? or
2. would there be a better way to achieve a direct import?

(error messages in detail below)

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:23: 
    RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'gtk' not found while handling absolute import
    import sys
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:30: 
    RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'gtk' not found while handling absolute import
    import gobject as _gobject
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: 
    RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'gtk' not found while handling absolute import
    from gtk import _gtk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing the compiled `__init__.pyc` seems to work here, using `import_module` instead of `import_source`. However, the import is still notably slow...

```
# done manually once
file,filename,descr=imp.find_module('gtk')
print file,filename,descr
```

script:

```
# script
gtk=imp.load_module('gtk',FILE,FILENAME,DESCRIPTION) # the respective values
# gtk=imp.load_module("gtk",None,"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk",('','',5))
from gtk import gdk
```